# Why would I want to use namespaces in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, namespaces

I've been taking a look at the use of **namespaces** in ActionScript 3, and honestly I can't see why they're needed. Does anyone have a convincing example of their use?

I'm also finding them strangely hard to implement.

Comment: What do you mean by "hard to implement"? You just put your code in a namespace of your choosing...

Comment: I suppose I moreso meant that I'm finding it hard to understand how namespaces are implemented and used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good write-up on namespaces: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/01/a_complete_guid.html

I avoid using them in my own code... but sometimes I need to use them when working with framework classes employ them.  For instance, `ObjectProxy` uses them.

They seem like a quirk of the language to me... and they seem like they are used to get around limitations of the language. (see comment below)

Comment: I had the same views which I why I never really looked into them. I'm just finding myself at a point now where I'm running out of things to learn when it comes to AS3. A very good link - thanks a bunch.

Comment: you should explain a bit more this statement: "seem like they are used to get around limitations of the language"

Comment: @goliatone: The one that jumps out is that AS3 has `internal` but does not have "friendly internals".  Meaning that you can't create multiple libraries that can explicitly access internals of each other. To get around this limitation, they use `mx_internal` as a convention.

Comment: Gensisio: I'm not sure I would consider the current `internal` implementation wrong. It would not make much sense to access internal methods from anywhere, that would make them public. To me, It makes sense to use namespaces to denote a special use of a method. Just my two cents ;)

Comment: @goliatone: I didn't say that the current `internal` implementation was wrong.  But, the lack of "friendly internals" in the language is a limitation. (good or bad isn't a judgement here, it is still a limitation).  Some languages (C# has friend assemblies... C++ has friend) implement a "friendly internal" feature that allows you to create multiple libraries in which they can see each other's internals, but nobody else can.  Not public, but friendly :)

They do that a lot in the Flex framework to indicate that things are meant to be shared among the different Flex libraries, but not for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching on usage of this namespace feature.

I stumbled upon another link with more comprehensive explanations with some example usage in the maashaack project: https://code.google.com/p/maashaack/wiki/Namespace

One example given is overriding access modifiers. Reproduced below:

```
package test
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public function ClassA()
        {
        }

        public function test( msg:String ):void
        {
           trace( msg );
        }

        protected function trace( msg:String ):void
        {
            public::trace( "[ " + msg + " ]" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are compile time uses of namespace:

- Sharing library internals across different packages.
- Aliasing package.
- Preventing name conflict.

Aliasing packages is possible with Flex SDK compiler and ShockScript. Normally, conflicting or confusing package-qualified names would be deambiguated like this:

```
com.qux.fn()
com.baz.fn()
```

But with aliasing:

```
namespace q = 'com.qux'
namespace b = 'com.baz'
q::fn()
b::fn()
```